# i am updating new xampp with old xampp mysql data folder

Tags: mysql, xampp

**After getting this issue  is xampp mysql**

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> ```
> This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>
> improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> entire log window on the forums
> ```

i am reinstalling xammp so what should i do to recover database can anyone one suggest me

i have copy database folder from C:\xampp\mysql\data
now what should i do to recover it manually

Comment: what you have tried to fix this problem?

Comment: ib_logfile() , ib_logfile1, ibdata1 i have deleted these all files

Comment: still i am seeing issue

Answer (score 1):

```
exit Xampp server
go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
delete the ibdata1 file
restart xampp server
```

Answer (score 1):

i am seeing 1000's of these type of files in mysql data folder what is happening here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxIT4.png)